# What happens to identity-hashcode when there are more objects than `int` can hold?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, hashcode

The method `System.identityHashCode(...)` is called that way, because it *identifies* objects, so two distinct objects can't have same identity-hashcode, right?

It returns an `int`. But what happens, on a system with huge amount of RAM, when the number of objects exceeds the integer range `2^32`?

Wouldn't it be a problem for `HashMap`s and `HashSet`s when operating on classes which don't override `equals` and `hashCode`?

**EDIT:**
If `int` is not enough, can I get some real unique ID for an object?

Comment: `~4.2*(10^9)`: I suggest to use simple `2^XXX` when talking about anything related to computers (ie. `2^32` is a range for integer).

Comment: `@Crozin` ok, changed. By the way, I have 2^0 computers, 2^1 monitors and about 2^5 audio-CDs ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it would just be a normal hash collision. Two unequal objects are allowed to return the same hash - it's just that then both of them will need to be compared for equality.

This isn't restricted to identity hashcodes - consider `String.hashCode()`. Obviously there are more possible strings than `int` values, so there must be at least one hash value which is the result of hashing multiple strings. A `HashMap`/`HashSet` would first take the hash code to quickly narrow down the set of possible matches to only those entries which have the same hash code, and then call `equals()` on each one in turn until it found a match or determined that none of the entries was equal to the given key.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a Java method to get some really unique ID of an object? I mean, the JVM can and must be able to do this, so why not the developer?

Comment: @java: Not that I'm aware of. The appropriate type would depend on the JVM in question, *and* that ID might change over time as it was moved around in memory by the GC.

Comment: @Jonik: Suppose you want to have a hash map which only considers object identity, and not normal equality - you wanted to store separate but equal strings separately, for example. You need to be able to test for object identity - that's easy via == - but you also need to be able to get an appropriate hash code. How would you do that without identityHashCode?

Comment: @Jonik: I think it's reasonably clear. It's basically saying, "if you were able to make a non-virtual call to `Object.hashCode()` for this object, what would it return?"

Answer (score 4):

Wrong. Any number of objects can have the same identityHashCode.

Comment: Additional: The only guarentee is that two objects with different identityHashCodes are not the same object.

Answer (score 2):

"can I get some real unique ID for an object?"  I would ask you what would you do with such an id?  Does it need to be unique at a given instant, over the life of the JVM, or globally across any number of systems?

You could generate a [UUID](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) for each object you want a unique id for.  However, duplicate ids are still theoretically possible, just highly unlikely.

Comment: To put highly unlikely in perspective: The chance of getting 1 duplicate ID when generating tens of trillions of them is as large as getting hit by a meteorite in a year (source: Wikipedia)

Comment: There are some types of data structures for which it can be useful to have an absolute sortable ID.  As an example, comparing two variables of type `String` which refer to the same instance is very fast.  Comparing two variables which refer to different instance that hold the same 5,000 characters is slow.  If one could identify which string was "older", and replace the reference to the newer instance with a reference to the older one, the act of comparing many strings against each other would cause matching strings to get consolidated.